# how to differentiate and integrate second order differential

Tags: calculus, integration, differential

when doing second order differential equation sometimes i suppose $y'=p$
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{dp}{dx}=\frac{dp}{dy}.\frac{dy}{dx}=p.\frac{dp}{dy}$$

what is the relation of chain rule with second order differential? 

$\displaystyle \frac{u"}{u'}+(1-\frac{1}{x-1})=0 $

I want to integrate this. Should i suppose $u'=b$ and $u"=b'$ ?

Or should I use $\displaystyle\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dp}{dy}.\frac{dy}{dx}=p.\frac{dp}{dy}$ ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have the case where $u$ (dependent variable) is missing. With the substitution $u'=y$ you get a first order linear differential equation:

$$y^{'}+\left(1-\frac1x\right)y=0$$

This first order differential equation can be solved by separating the variables.

---

If the independent variable is missing then you use

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{dp}{dx}=\frac{dp}{dy}.\frac{dy}{dx}=p.\frac{dp}{dy}$$

Example:

$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=-\frac{2}{1-y}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2$

$\frac{dy}{dx}=p \quad (\color{blue}*)$

$p\frac{dp}{dy}=-\frac{2}{1-y} \cdot p^2$

Dividing the equation by $p^2$ and multipling it by $dy$

$\frac{dp}{p}=-\frac{2}{1-y} \ dy$

$p=c_1\cdot (1-y)^2$

We can use $*$ and get $\frac{dy}{dx}=c_1\cdot (1-y)^2$.

After  the variables has been separated this differential equation can be solved as well.

Comment: hello thanks for answering my question! i have some questions, in case when dependent variable is missing, $u'=y$, is $u'=du/dx$ ? and $y'=dy/dx$? and when independent variable is missing, the purpose to find p is to find the function? thanks!

Comment: You have a typo. It is $u^{\color{red}{''}}=\frac{du}{dx}$. Yes, you have to find  $p$ since $p=\frac{dy}{dx}$

Comment: here when im doing separation variable $y^{'}+\left(1-\frac1x\right)y=0$ is the same with $\frac{dy}{dx}+(1-\frac{1}{x-1})=0$ ? and $u'=y$ -> $y=\frac{du}{dy}$ so $ u^{\color{red}{''}}=\frac{du}{dx}$ ??

Comment: @DevinaMuljono To be clear you don´t need $u^{''}$. If you have calculated $y$ then you integrate $y$ to obtain $u$.

Comment: $u'=y=c_1\cdot (e^{-x}\cdot x-e^{-x})$ Now you have to integrate to obtain $u(x)$. This is what we want.

Comment: my idea is like this $\frac{dy}{dx}=-(1-\frac{1}{x-1})y$ and $\int \frac{dy}{y}=\int-(1-\frac{1}{x-1})dx$ so i will get $y=e^-x(x-1)C$ since $u'=y$ so $\int\frac{du}{dx}=\int e^-x(x-1)C$ to get $u(x)$ so my question is $y^{'}=\frac{dy}{dx}$ or$ \frac{dy}{du}$?

Comment: Your calculation is right. It´s the same result as I have. And $y^{'}=\frac{dy}{dx}$. You have to use partial integration to obtain $y=\int e^{-x}\cdot (x-1)\cdot C$, in particular $\int e^{-x}\cdot x=\int a^{'}\cdot b=a\cdot b-\int a \cdot b^{'} \, dx=-e^{-x}\cdot x-\int -e^{-x}$.

Comment: ah okay!! Thanks!! Is there another way besides doing separation like this?

Comment: @DevinaMuljono You´re welcome. I don´t see another (simpler) method.